# c# excel insert checking if the sheet exist

Tags: c#, excel

```
   using (DbCommand command = oconn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [Sheet2$] (F1 number, F2 char(255), F3 char(128))";
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
                    {
                        //now we insert the values into the existing sheet...no new sheet is added.
                        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Sheet2$] (F1, F2, F3) VALUES(1,\"Fake Record\",\"Fake Record\")";
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
```

I am using this code to insert some records in excel file sheet . What i want to do is to see if for example Sheet1 is there then create sheet 2 and insert these records there . and if it only finds sheet 3 then i want to create another sheet4 and insert the records there and so on. how can i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to check the tables of the data schema:

```
DataTable dtSchema = oconn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

DataRow[] dr = dtSchema.Select("TABLE_NAME = 'Sheet1$'");

bool exist = dr == null || dr.Length == 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The same solution we can find here: https://mudassarkhan.wordpress.com/tag/c-excel/